# How do I configure Visual Studio 10 to publish my font files?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, iis-7.5, publish

When "Publish[ing] Website" from Visual Studio 10 to IIS7.5, I find that some of the relevant font files for my site are left behind and not pushed out to the server.

How do I make sure that the files are properly copied over? Is there a setting that forces files to be copied over?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you specify a Build Action of "Content" for whatever files you want included when published. By default, unknown files types have a build action of "None" and publishing skips them.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the case by case inclusion of these files, there are scripts available to configure VS to deploy these values by default

Here is the case by case article
http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2010/07/02/Visual-Studio-default-build-action-for-non-default-file-types.aspx

Here is a generator of a config file to do this be default (referenced in above article)
http://tools.andreloker.de/dbag